# How to run function whenever the app appears on screen in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a function which I want to run whenever the app appears on screen.
I tried all these methods:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    generateRandomNumber()

}
override func viewDidAppear() {
    generateRandomNumber()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    generateRandomNumber()
}
```

Although the function runs every time I run app, but if after running app I press home botton and come back to app (didn't terminated the app) then the function does not execute again.

Update: I tried using following code in my ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }
    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
        generateRandomNumber()
    }
```

But it takes about a second to run. Is there a better way?

Comment: appwillEnterForeground in appdelegate.

Comment: Your updated code looks fine. I suspect when you say "it takes about a second to run" that you're measuring at the wrong point. Put a breakpoint in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, or add a print statement. I suspect it runs much sooner than you think and that you're probably not updating your views to match.

Comment: will it be even more faster if I use `applicationWillEnterForeground`?

Comment: That happens slightly before "active," but it should be nowhere near 1 second. It really has to do with whether you want system alerts, incoming phone calls and the like to trigger it. It's not about performance.

Comment: I was trying to just replace `applicationDidBecomeActive ` with `applicationWillEnterForeground ` in the updated code above but it didn't work.
can you please show me how to use `applicationWillEnterForeground` in ViewController.swift?

Answer (score 6):

In your application delegate, you want to implement `applicationDidBecomeActive`. Note that this will also run when things like system alerts are dismissed. If you only want to run something when returning from the background, you want `applicationWillEnterForeground`. For full details, see "Managing State Transitions" in the [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate) documentation and [Strategies for Handling App State Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html) in the App Programming Guide.

Your approach looks basically right; in order to use `willEnterForeground` rather than `didBecomeActive`, it's just a small change:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground),
                                           name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
                                           object: nil)
}

@objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: Notification) {
    generateRandomNumber()
}
```

The only thing to be careful with here is that this observer continues to be in force as long as the view controller exists, even if it's not currently on the screen (the most common case of that is when it's presented other view controllers). In some cases that's a problem, and you should call `addObserver` in `viewWillAppear` and `removeObserver` in `viewDidDisappear` instead of using `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I am new to swift and having a little difficulty understanding apple documentation. Can you please tell me when should I right my generateRandomNumber() function.
generateRandomNumber() is located in ViewController.swift